# JS/jQuery - Validate start time and end time on a HTML document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a PHP/HTML page which uses some javascript and jQuery features. I have little to no experience of these coding languages.

I use libraries and tools, so i will list those incase they have the option to provide the solution to my question. Using the current libraries i simply have to type 'required' into the end of an input tag e.g. `input name="end_time" type="text" id="end_time" required`

I use jQuery timepicker, to select a time by choosing an hour and minutes by 15 minute intervals. What I want to do is ensure that the start time, cannot be greater than the end time.

I've done some research into javascript/jquery and so far I have:

```
function validateTime(){
var time_1 = document.getElementById("start_time").value;
var time_2 = document.getElementById("end_time").value;
 if (time_1 > time_2) {
  alert("It appears you chose a start time which is later than your end time.");
 }
}
```

In theory this should work, but this kind of alert is annoying. Not to mention it would probably run before any input is even entered into the end time input. I would be very interested to know if I could use some of the built in validation popups for this as I want to avoid using an alert.

These are the jQuery files I reference:

code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js

code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js

Here is an example of how the default validation popups look: http://oi60.tinypic.com/246lxeu.jpg

I'm a complete amateur when it comes to javascript, and I just happened upon this validation and it works great for what I currently use it for, but I don't have any understanding of which file includes the validation and what is possible using it. If its possible i'd love to use the validation included in jQuery for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given up on JS, PHP validation will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `oninvalid event`, you just need to specify the pattern, whether its an alpha numeric or a text or a number.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"
oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Plz enter on Alphabets ')" />
```

Here's an updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zpkKv/181/)

Comment: This looks promising, is there any way i can modify this to work similarly to the function in my post?

Comment: Check the updated fiddle. There's two example in it.

Comment: I checked out the fiddle but it doesn't seem to allow me to trigger a validation error based on the function(or similar) to my original post. I need the validation to check whether the start time is greater than end time, and if it is - then trigger the validation message.